# comparing two files with common file name but want output from the both if matched, how using awk?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I want to compare filenames of Today.txt with Main.txt.
If there is match, then print all 6 columns of matched file of Main.txt and Time column of Today.txt with a new file say matched.txt.

and the files which are not matched with Main.txt, then list the filename and time of TODAY.txt in a new file say unmatched.txt

NOTE: Plus sign(+) indicates files are from inprogress directory,sometimes filenames are appended with "+".

Main.txt

```
date      filename          timestamp space  count   status
Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time
```

Today.txt

```
 filename       time
CHCK01_20161104.txt 06:03
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
AR01_20161104.txt   09:36
AR02_20161104.txt   09:36
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:16
```

Required Output:
matched.txt

```
Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39  06:03 2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03  09:16 0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31  09:36 0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31  09:36 0.04M  433      On_Time
```

unmatched.txt

```
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
```

Below command gives me proper output except the 2nd column output of Today.txt, kindly help me on this please ?

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}
 NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}
 {k=$3; sub(/^\+/,"",k)} k in a{print; delete a[k]}
 END{for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched.txt"}' Today.txt Main.txt > matched.txt
```

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Does the `main.txt` and `today.txt` have headers as shown in example?

Comment: yes, There are headers are there, but I don't want headers in my matched or unmatched output, thanks

Comment: And are these files in `today.txt` gonna occur exactly once in the `main.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the filenames in `today.txt` occur only once in the `main.tx`, you can write an awk script as

```
$ cat prog.awk
NR==FNR && NR>1{file[$1]=$2; next}
$3 in file{$4 = $4" "file[$3]; print > "matched.txt"; delete file[$3]}
END{for (filename in file) print filename, file[filename] > "unmatched.txt"}

$ awk -F"[ +]*" -f prog.awk today main
```

- `-F"[ +]*"` Set the field separator as space or `+`. This will be use full to remove the `+` from the filenames.

Comment: Can you suggest me what need be changed in my written code (code in my que) ?